# How to make html button redirect like an anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I am new to `stackoverflow` and I want some quick help here. Actually I am in `learning` phase now and I want to know how to visit a new page on `button` `click`. Like `<a href='mypage'></a>` That means, if I am on page 1 I want to go to page 2.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

if we use `anchor` tag and add `href` `value` it will `redirect` us to new page

```
<a href='mypage'>Click ME</a>
```

**But i need to know if we use `button` how can i `redirect` to specific page like anchor tag!**

How can I achieve this?

Sorry if this requirement is too low for you, but its kind of first step to me.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Way 1 :

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'www.example.com';">www.example.com</button>
```

Way 2 :

```
<button id="button">www.example.com</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.example.com";
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way.

```
<input type='button' value='redirect' class="btn" onclick="document.location.href='www.google.com';"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Wrap button tags with `<a href>`

   ```
   <a href='mypage'><button>Click ME</button></a>
   ```
2. Wrap `<a href>` with button tags

   ```
   <button><a href='mypage'>Click ME</a></button>
   ```